# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (2x720 and 784x10)

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Any ideas how I can fix this run time error?

I would like to create these layers to read in the mnist dataset:

1. A 2d convolutional layer with 10 filters of size 5x5 with stride 1, zero padding, followed
   by a ReLU activation, then a 2d max pooling operation with size 2x2.
2. A 2d convolutional layer with 20 filters of size 5x5 with stride 1, zero padding, followed
   by a ReLU activation, then a 2d max pooling operation with size 2x2.
3. Fully-connected layer followed by a ReLU activation.

```
class CNN(torch.nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        super().__init__()
        self.flatten = torch.nn.Flatten(start_dim=1)
        self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 1, out_channels = 10, kernel_size = 5, stride = 1,
                      padding = 1, padding_mode = 'zeros')
        self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 10, out_channels = 20, kernel_size = 5, stride = 1,
                      padding = 1, padding_mode = 'zeros')
        self.fc = torch.nn.Linear(input_size, output_size)
        self.max_pool2d = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2)
        self.act = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.log_softmax = torch.nn.LogSoftmax(dim = 1)
        # ------------------
    
    def forward(self, x):
        # ------------------
        # Write your implementation here.        
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.act(x)
        x = self.max_pool2d(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.act(x)
        x = self.max_pool2d(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        # x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.act(self.fc(x))
        y_output = self.log_softmax(x)
        
        return y_output
        # ------------------

model = CNN().to(DEVICE)

# sanity check
print(model)
from torchsummary import summary
summary(model, (1,32,32))
```

Running into a wall since I don't know how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the network details that you provided:

> I need to create:
>
> 1. A 2d convolutional layer with 10 filters of size 5x5 with stride 1, zero padding, followed by a ReLU activation, then a 2d max pooling operation with size 2x2.
> 2. A 2d convolutional layer with 20 filters of size 5x5 with stride 1, zero padding, followed by a ReLU activation, then a 2d max pooling operation with size 2x2.
> 3. Fully-connected layer followed by a ReLU activation.

The following model should do the job:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
        # assuming you have 1 input channels, replace 1 here with your choice of input channels
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=0),
                                        nn.ReLU(),
                                        nn.MaxPool2d(2))
        
        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=0),
                                        nn.ReLU(),
                                        nn.MaxPool2d(2),
                                        nn.Flatten())
        
        #assuming input is 1 channels with height and width 32, and output of fc is 10
        self.linear = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(500, 10),
                                    nn.ReLU())

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.linear(x)
        return x
```

The above model should work.